# Looping through 2 arrays - Find Header in a table then paste value in correct location

Tags: excel, vba

In an effort to clean up my code I want to see if there is a way to loop through some of my repetitive code. The objective is to paste a new project into a project tracker, then proceed to paste the correct data in the row that the project is in and column that matches the destination header.

In the past, I have copied and pasted the code and then filled in the name of the column and the data I needed to be pasted there as seen by the code labeled Loop 1 and Loop 2. The Private Sub TestLoop is passed the values from another macro. I have a lot of other things to debug once I figure out the basics of how this loop with work but my starting code is below. Thank you for your support.

```
        Private destWB                      As Workbook
        Private destSht                     As Worksheet
        Private destProjectTracker          As Worksheet
        Private Loc                         As Range
        Private PriorityNo                  As String
        Private TrackingNo                  As String

        Private Sub DeclareVariables()
        destFileName = ThisWorkbook.Names("MasterProjectTrackerLocation").RefersToRange.Value
        Set destWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=destFileName, Password:="", UpdateLinks:=3)
        Set destProjectTracker = destWB.Sheets("Master Project Tracker")
        End Sub


        Private Sub TestLoop(TrackingNo As String, PriorityNo As String, ProjectName As String)
        Dim Itm
        Call DeclareVariables
        Set destSht = destProjectTracker

        'Set cell that Project Name is copied into
        Set Loc = destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        Loc.Value = ProjectName

        For Each Itm In Array("TrackingNo, PriorityNo")

            'Loop 1
                    strSearch = "Tracking No" 'This finds the column labeled "Tracking No" in a table
                    Set aCell = destSht.Rows(3).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                        vOffset = aCell.Column - 1 'Determines the offset amount from the Project Name location
                        Loc.Offset(0, vOffset) = TrackingNo 'Paste the Tracking No into that cell
                    End If

            'Loop 2
                    strSearch = "Priority No" 'This finds the column labeled "Priority No" in a table
                    Set aCell = destSht.Rows(3).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                        vOffset = aCell.Column - 1 'Determines the offset amount from the Project Name location
                        Loc.Offset(0, vOffset) = PriorityNo 'Paste the Priority No into that cell
                    End If

            'Etc

        Next Itm

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are trying to loop through an array of two strings.  Personally, I find the 'array' for-loop method a little dirty, and instead prefer the following:

```
Dim a As Integer
Dim StringList(1 To 2) As Variant

StringList(1) = "TrackingNo"
StringList(2) = "PriorityNo"

For a = LBound(StringList, 1) To UBound(StringList, 2)
    'Everytime you want to use the string from the variant, _
      simply call it using the following:
      MsgBox CStr(StringList(a))
Next a
```

Also, I can see that you are needing to find a column header, which can simply be put into a common function.  I have done this many times and the following function is perfect for that.  It's up to you if you want to check for cases where the function returns '0' (didn't find the requested text in any column).

```
Public Function GetColumn(Sht As Worksheet, _
                           ColumnHeaderText As String, _
                           Optional RowToCheck As Integer = 1, _
                           Optional Strict As Boolean = False) As Integer
'// By reference of a specific sheet, the column number is returned by
'// searching for specific text in a defined row.
Dim a As Integer
Dim Timeout As Integer

Timeout = 0
GetColumn = 0
For a = 1 To 2000
    If Len(Sht.Cells(RowToCheck, a).Value) = 0 Then
        Timeout = Timeout + 1
    End If
    If Timeout >= 10 Then
        Exit For
    End If
    If Strict = True Then
        If Sht.Cells(RowToCheck, a).Value = ColumnHeaderText Then
            GetColumn = a
            Exit For
        End If
    Else
        If InStr(1, Trim(UCase(Sht.Cells(RowToCheck, a).Value)), Trim(UCase(ColumnHeaderText)), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            GetColumn = a
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next a
End Function
```

Putting it together, and if I am reading this correctly (and I apologize, but I did not dummy up a spreadsheet to test this, but I use this code all the time to do what you're talking about), we can now loop through a predefined array of strings, and then loop through your spreadsheet to locate the correct columns using the following code:

```
Option Explicit '<---You should always have this at the very top...makes good sense.

Private destWB                      As Workbook
Private destSht                     As Worksheet
Private destProjectTracker          As Worksheet
Private Loc                         As Range
Private PriorityNo                  As String
Private TrackingNo                  As String

Private Sub DeclareVariables()
destFileName = ThisWorkbook.Names("MasterProjectTrackerLocation").RefersToRange.Value
Set destWB = Workbooks.Open(destFileName, 3, , , "")
Set destProjectTracker = destWB.Sheets("Master Project Tracker")
End Sub

Private Sub TestLoop(TrackingNo As String, PriorityNo As String, ProjectName As String)
' <Say what your function does here>
Dim a As Integer
Dim StringList(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Variant
Dim TargetRow As Integer

StringList(1, 1) = "TrackingNo"
StringList(1, 2) = TrackingNo
StringList(2, 1) = "PriorityNo"
StringList(2, 2) = PriorityNo
' Continue to add as necessary, but would be better to pass in the variant as a parameter

Call DeclareVariables

If Not destProjectTracker Is Nothing Then
    Set destSht = destProjectTracker

    'Set cell that Project Name is copied into
    TargetRow = destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    destSht.Cells(TargetRow, 1).Value = ProjectName

    For a = LBound(StringList, 1) To UBound(StringList, 2)
        'Verify the header row being called here (should it be '3' as you coded before?)
        destSht.Cells(TargetRow, GetColumn(destSht, CStr(StringList(a, 1)), 3, True)).Value = CStr(StringList(a, 2))
    Next a
End If

End Function

Public Function GetColumn(Sht As Worksheet, _
                           ColumnHeaderText As String, _
                           Optional RowToCheck As Integer = 1, _
                           Optional Strict As Boolean = False) As Integer
'// By reference of a specific sheet, the column number is returned by
'// searching for specific text in a defined row.
Dim a As Integer
Dim Timeout As Integer

Timeout = 0
GetColumn = 0
For a = 1 To 2000
    If Len(Sht.Cells(RowToCheck, a).Value) = 0 Then
        Timeout = Timeout + 1
    End If
    If Timeout >= 10 Then
        Exit For
    End If
    If Strict = True Then
        If Sht.Cells(RowToCheck, a).Value = ColumnHeaderText Then
            GetColumn = a
            Exit For
        End If
    Else
        If InStr(1, Trim(UCase(Sht.Cells(RowToCheck, a).Value)), Trim(UCase(ColumnHeaderText)), vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            GetColumn = a
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next a
End Function
```

Comment: this answer is very thorough. I am grateful for the time you took to share this method with me. I will test this and let you know my results.

Comment: I just completed the code. It worked marvelously. Thank you very much!

Comment: How do I add additional variables? I tried adding more than just 2. 23 pairs to be exact. But the loop always stops at 2. Am I forgetting to adjust something?